# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

> Prove that$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+\frac43G$$

I've found this integral in my notebook and perhaps I encountered it before since it looks quite familiar.
Anyway I thought it's quite a trivial integral so I'm gonna solve it quickly, but I am having some hard time to finish it. I went on with Feynman's trick:

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln((1+x^2)a+x)}{1+x^2}dx\Rightarrow I'(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{a+x+ax^2}$$
$$=\frac1a\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\left(x+\frac{1}{2a}\right)^2+1-\frac{1}{4a^2}}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4a^2}}}\arctan\left(\frac{x+\frac{1}{2a}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4a^2}}}\right)\bigg|_0^\infty$$$$=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{4a^2-1}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{4a^2-1}}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4a^2-1}}\right)=\frac{2\arctan\left(\sqrt{4a^2-1}\right)}{\sqrt{4a^2-1}}$$
We can prove easily via the substitution $x\to \frac{1}{x}$ that $I(0)=0$ so we have that:
$$I=I(1)-I(0)=2\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{4a^2-1}\right)}{\sqrt{4a^2-1}}da$$
Now I thought about two substitutions:
$$ \overset{a=\frac12\cosh x}=\int_{\operatorname{arccosh}(0)}^{\operatorname{arccosh}(2)} \arctan(\sinh x)dx$$
$$\overset{a=\frac12\sec x}=\int_{\operatorname{arcsec}(0)}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{x}{\cos x}dx$$
But in both cases the lower bound is annoying and I think I am missing something here (maybe obvious).
So I would love to get some help in order to finish this.

---

Edit: We can apply once again Feynman's trick. First consider: $$I(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{2\arctan(t\sqrt{4a^2-1})}{\sqrt{4a^2-1}}da\Rightarrow I'(t)=2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+t^2(4a^2-1)}da$$
$$=\frac{1}{t\sqrt{1-t^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{2at}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right)\bigg|_0^1=\frac{1}{t\sqrt{1-t^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{2t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right)$$
So once again we have $I(0)=0$, so $I=I(1)-I(0)$.
$$\Rightarrow I=\int_0^1\frac{1}{t\sqrt{1-t^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{2t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right)dt\overset{t=\sin x}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\arctan(2\tan x)}{\sin x}dx$$
At this point Mathematica can evaluate the integral to be:
$$I=\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+\frac43G$$
I didn't try the last integral yet, but I am thinking of Feynman again $\ddot \smile$.

---

Edit 2: Found that I already was on it some time ago, and actually posted it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3000330/515527), which means I have solved it before using Feynman's trick, but right now I can't remember how I did it.

So given the circumstances I am positive that it can be solved starting with my approach, but if you have any other ways then feel free to share it.

Comment: The integral is complex for $a\in(-1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: And after $n$ applications of Feynman, you come back to the original integral. :)

Comment: Well, it's not hard to reduce the problem to finding $$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\log\left(1+\frac12\sin x\right)\mathrm dx$$ I remember a post on AoPS about a similair integral, namely with a variable instead of the $\frac12$ but I cannot find the post right now.

Comment: @Zacky No, that's not all; but that's the part I cannot solve by myself `^^'`

Comment: @Zacky Precisely! I think there is a possible way of solving this integral using Clausen's Function but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: @MrTaurho: i was leading to consider the same integral ;)

Comment: @FDP Now all that we need is a suitable method to find the value of this one :)

Comment: I'm wondering if a simple change of variable in the original integral is not enough to compute it

Comment: Or, maybe consider $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\log\left(1+\alpha\sin x\right)\mathrm dx$

Comment: @FDP I have seen this parametrized integral before somewhere on AoPS. But I have no idea how to find the thread I am refering to...

Comment: I think If you know how to compute $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln(x^2+3)}{1+x^2}\,dx$ you can compute $I$

Comment: @FDP Feynman's trick all the way! Consider: $$I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln((1+x^2)a+2)}{1+x^2}dx$$ In fact I have solved it here (but reversed): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3195105/515527. But I don't see how to make the connection.

Comment: Found what I was searching for https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h1735425p11265363

Comment: Zacky:  I bet it's easier to consider $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln(1+a^2x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx$

Comment: @Zacky The thread proposing the integral $\int_0^\frac\pi2\log(a+\sin x)\mathrm dx$ was even posted by yourself ;)

Comment: @mrtaurho I remember now, I was actually trying to solve this one back then: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3044892/515527. However I took it my way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 3**. Consider the following integral:
$$ I(a)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\arctan(a\tan x)}{\sin x}dx\Rightarrow I'(a)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sec x}{1+a^2\tan^2 x}dx$$
$$ =\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos x}{\cos^2 x+a^2\sin^2 x}dx\overset{\sin x=y}=\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{1+(a^2-1)y^2}=\frac{\arctan\sqrt{a^2-1}}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$

$$\rm I=\underbrace{I(2)-I(1)}_{=J}+I(1), \quad  I(1)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx$$

$$J=\int_1^2 \frac{\arctan\sqrt{a^2-1}}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}da\overset{a=\sec x}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}\frac{x}{\cos x}dx\overset{x=\frac{\pi}{2}-t}=\int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-t}{\sin t}dt$$
$$\rm=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{\sin t}dt- \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{t}{\sin t}dt+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{6} \frac{t}{\sin t}dt$$
$$ \Rightarrow I=J+I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\left(\tan \frac{x}{2}\right)\bigg|_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{6} \frac{t}{\sin t}dt$$
Finally, using the result from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3044892/515527), we get:
$$ I=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)-\frac{\pi}{6}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+\frac43G=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+\frac43G}$$

---

**Solution 4.**
$$I=\int_0^2\frac{\arctan\sqrt{a^2-1}}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}da=\int_0^2\frac{\operatorname{arcsec} a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}da$$

$$\sf I=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{arcsec} a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}da+\int_1^2\frac{\operatorname{arcsec} a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}da$$
The second integral is like the one from above, and for the first integral we need to use the complex definition of $\sf \arccos z$, namely $\sf -i\ln\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)$.
$$\sf \Rightarrow \frac{\operatorname{arcsec} a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}=\frac{-\ln\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}\right)}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$$
And now via the substitution $a=\sin y$ everything goes smoothly.

Answer (score 8):

Start by letting $x\mapsto\tan x$ we obtain
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx\stackrel{x\mapsto\tan x}=\int_0^\frac\pi2\log(1+\tan x+\tan^2x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^\frac\pi2\log\left(\frac{1+\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2x}\right)\mathrm dx$$
Splitting the logarithm we are left with a standard integral, solvable by differentiating the Beta Function for instance, and another one which I already referred to within the comments. To be precise we get
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\frac\pi2\log\left(\frac{1+\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2x}\right)\mathrm dx&=\pi\log 2+\int_0^\frac\pi2\log(1+\sin x\cos x)\mathrm dx\\
&=\pi\log 2+2\int_0^\frac\pi4\log\left(1+\frac12\sin2x\right)\mathrm dx\\
&=\pi\log 2+\int_0^\frac\pi2\log\left(1+\frac12\sin x\right)\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac\pi2\log2+\int_0^\frac\pi2\log\left(2+\sin x\right)\mathrm dx
\end{align*}
The latter integral $-$ even a more general case $-$ is examined within [this AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h1735425p11265363). An expression is deduced by the user *gustin33*. I won't copy his derivation here since his own solution is impressive enough. For the given case he obtained
$$\int_0^\frac\pi2\log\left(2+\sin x\right)\mathrm dx=\frac{4G}3+\frac\pi3\log(2+\sqrt3)-\frac\pi2\log2 $$
Which overall yields to the result.

> $$\therefore~\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx~=~\frac{4G}3+\frac\pi3\log(2+\sqrt3)$$

The crucial point of the linked post is the identity
$$\int_0^\frac\pi2\log(a+\sin x)\mathrm dx=2\operatorname{Ti}_2(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})-\frac\pi2(\log2+\cosh^{-1}a)$$
For $a=2$ the result follows. I will see if I can find another proof for this identity; otherwise I will just leave this here.

---

**EDIT I**

Maybe I am on the right track now! Using the integral representation for the Dilogarithm used in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3029789/proving-im-operatornameli-2-sqrt-i-sqrt-2-1-frac34g-frac18-pi-ln-sqrt/3061998#3061998) and reexpressing the Inverse Tangent Integral in terms of the Dilogarithm aswell we obtain
$$\small
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Ti}_2(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})&=\frac1{2i}\left[\operatorname{Li}_2(ia+i\sqrt{a^2-1})-\operatorname{Li}_2(-ia+-i\sqrt{a^2-1})\right]\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left[\int_0^1\frac{ia+i\sqrt{a^2-1}}{(ia+i\sqrt{a^2-1})t-1}\log t\mathrm dt-\int_0^1\frac{-ia+-i\sqrt{a^2-1}}{(-ia+-i\sqrt{a^2-1})t-1}\log t\mathrm dt\right]\\
&=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}2\int_0^1\left[\frac1{(-1)+i(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})t}+\frac1{(-1)-i(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})t}\right]\log t\mathrm dt\\
&=-(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})\int_0^1\frac{\log t}{1+(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})^2t^2}\mathrm dt
\end{align*}
$$
Mabye this integral is useful for someone. I will try to find something from which it is useful to me too.

---

**EDIT II**

The integral can also be reduced to finding
$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan t}{t^2+t+1}\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\mathrm dt$$
I am almost certain I have seen this one before aswell. I will search for it.

Comment: Feynman's trick doesn't work fine for $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln(1+ax^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx$ because of $1$

Comment: @FDP Were you trying the same approach as I posted in my answer?

Comment: @Zacky: Yes but now i try to find out something else. Reverse engineering, 2G/3 is obtainable by  an integral, something related to $\dfrac{\pi}{12}$ and $\pi\ln(2+\sqrt{3})$ is related to $\dfrac{\pi}{12}$ as well.

Comment: Thanks ! It's nice but a proof without using Feynman's trick would be nicer for me.

Answer (score 8):

**Solution 1.**

By splitting the integral at $1$ and letting $x\to \frac{1}{x}$ in the second part, we get:$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$$
Via the substitution $x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}\Rightarrow dx=-\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}dt$ and using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant#Integral_identities), we obtain:
$$I=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{3+t^2}{(1+t)^2}\right)}{1+t^2}dt+2G=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(3+t^2)}{1+t^2}dt-4\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2}+2G$$
The second one is [a well known Putnam integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155941/515527), and for the first one we can try to use Feynman's trick.
$$I=2J-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2+2G, \quad J=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(3+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$J(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(2+a(1+x^2))}{1+x^2}dx\Rightarrow J'(a)=\frac1a\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\frac{a+2}{a}+x^2}dx$$
$$=\frac1a\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+2}}\arctan\left(x\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+2}}\right)\bigg|_0^1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a(a+2)}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+2}}\right)$$
We are looking to find $J=J(1)$, but we also have: $J(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2$ so:
$$J=J(1)-J(0)+J(0)=\underbrace{\int_0^1 J'(a)da}_{=K}+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2 $$
Now letting $\sqrt{\frac{a+2}{a}}=x\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{a(a+2)}}da=-a dx=-\frac{2}{x^2-1}dx\,$ gives us:
$$K=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{a(a+2)}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+2}}\right)da=2\int_\sqrt 3^\infty \frac{\arctan \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2-1}dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)-2\int_{\sqrt 3}^\infty \frac{\arctan x}{x^2-1}dx
$$
$$H=2\int_{\sqrt 3}^\infty \frac{\arctan x}{x^2-1}dx\overset{x=\tan t}=-2\int_\frac{\pi}{3}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{t}{\cos(2t)}dt\overset{\large 2t=x+\frac{\pi}{2}}=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2}}{\sin x}dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)\bigg|_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac12 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx-\frac12\int_0^\frac{\pi}{6}\frac{x}{\sin x}dx$$
The last two integrals are linked in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3048431/515527) and using their values we get:
$$H=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+G+\frac{\pi}{12}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)-\frac23G=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+\frac13G}$$
$$\Rightarrow \boxed{K=\frac{\pi}{6}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)-\frac13G}\Rightarrow \boxed{J=\frac{\pi}{6}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln  2-\frac13G}$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+\frac43G}$$

---

**Solution 2.**

We can start by considering:
$$A=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(2+\sin x)dx,\quad B=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2-\sin x)dx$$
Like in *mrtaurho*'s approach we have:
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2 +A=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2+\frac12\left((A+B)+(A-B)\right)\tag 1$$
A solution for $A-B\,$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3044892/515527).
$$A-B=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\left(\frac{2+\sin x}{2-\sin x}\right)dx=-\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2+\sqrt 3) +\frac{8}{3}G\tag2$$
And for $A+B$ we can directly use this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3086231/515527).
$$A+B=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(4-\sin^2 x)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(4\cos^2x +3\sin^2 x)dx$$$$=\pi \ln 2 +\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln\left(\cos^2 x+\frac34 \sin^2 x\right)dx=\pi\ln\left(1+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)\tag3$$
Now plugging $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$ yields the result.

$$\boxed{I=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2+\frac12\left(\pi\ln(2+\sqrt 3)-\pi \ln 2-\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+\frac83G\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+\frac43G}$$

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}I&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx\\
\end{align}
In the latter integral perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$

\begin{align}I&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx+2\text{G} \end{align}
Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$,
\begin{align}I&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(3+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx+2\text{G}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 3+2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3}\right)}{1+x^2}dx-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx+2\text{G}\\
 \end{align}

Define $F$ on $[0;1]$ by,
\begin{align}F(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+a^2x^2)}{1+x^2}dx\end{align}
Observe that, $\displaystyle F(0)=0,F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3}\right)}{1+x^2}dx$.

\begin{align}F^\prime (a)&=\int_0^1 \frac{2a x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2x^2)}dx\\
&=2\left[a\left(\frac{\arctan x}{a^2-1}-\frac{\arctan(ax)}{a(a^2-1)}\right)\right]_0^1\\
&=\frac{\pi a}{2(a^2-1)}-\frac{2\arctan a}{a^2-1}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{ a}{a^2-1}\,da+2\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{\arctan a}{1-a^2}\,da\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\Big[\ln(1-a^2)\Big]_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}+2\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{\arctan a}{1-a^2}\,da\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+2\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{\arctan a}{1-a^2}\,da\\
\end{align}
Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-a}{1+a}$,
\begin{align}F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^1\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)}{a}\,da\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\frac{\pi}{4}\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^1\frac{1}{a}\,da-\left(\int_0^1\frac{\arctan a}{a}\,da-\int_0^{2-\sqrt{3}}\frac{\arctan a}{a}\,da\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)-\text{G}+\int_0^{2-\sqrt{3}}\frac{\arctan a}{a}\,da\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)-\text{G}+\Big[\arctan a\ln a\Big]_0^{2-\sqrt{3}}-\int_0^{2-\sqrt{3}}\frac{\ln a}{1+a^2}\,da\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{\pi}{6}\ln\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)-\text{G}-\int_0^{2-\sqrt{3}}\frac{\ln a}{1+a^2}\,da\\
\end{align}
Perform the change of variable $\displaystyle a=\tan u$,
\begin{align}F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{\pi}{6}\ln\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)-\text{G}-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{12}}\ln(\tan u)\,du\end{align}
The last integral value is $-\dfrac{2}{3}\text{G}$

(see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/987972/186817 )

Therefore,
\begin{align}F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{\pi}{6}\ln\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)-\dfrac{1}{3}\text{G}\end{align}

it is well known that,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{8}\pi\ln 2\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}I&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 3+\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{\pi}{3}\ln\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)-\dfrac{2}{3}\text{G}-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2+2\text{G}\\
&=\dfrac{4}{3}\text{G}-\frac{\pi}{3}\ln\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)\\
&=\boxed{\dfrac{4}{3}\text{G}+\frac{\pi}{3}\ln\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}
\end{align}
**NB:**

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$,
\begin{align}K&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln 2}{1+x^2}\,dx-K\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\pi\ln 2-K
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}K&=\frac{1}{8}\pi\ln 2\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Note $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=0$ and substitute $x=\tan \frac t2$ to rewrite the integral
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx
= \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln(1+2\sec t)dt
\end{align}
Let $J(a) = \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln(1+\sec a\sec t)dt$
$$J’(a)= \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\sec a\tan a }{\sec a+\cos t}dt
=a\sec a
$$
$$J(0)= \int_0^{\frac\pi2}[\underset{t\to\frac\pi2-t}{\ln(1+\cos t)}- \ln\cos t]dt
= \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\sec t+\tan t)dt
$$
Then
\begin{align}
I&= J(\frac\pi3)=J(0)+\int_0^{\frac\pi3} J’(a)da 
=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln (\tan t+\sec t) dt
+ \int_0^{\frac\pi3} a\sec a \>\overset{ibp}{da}\\
&= \frac\pi3 \ln\left(\tan  \frac\pi3 +\sec  \frac\pi3\right)+ \int_{ \frac\pi3} ^{\frac\pi2} 
{\ln(\tan a+\sec a) da} \>\>\>\>\>(a=\frac\pi2-2\theta)\\&= \frac\pi3 \ln(2+\sqrt3)-2 \int^{ \frac\pi{12}}_{0} 
\ln\tan\theta \>d\theta
= \frac\pi3 \ln(2+\sqrt3)+\frac43G
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

****One more** by Feynman’s Technique**

Parameterising our integral
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+x+x^{2}\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x$$
by the integral
$$
I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+2 x \sin a+x^{2}\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x,
$$
where $a\in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]. $

Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2 x \cos a}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+2 x \sin a+x^{2}\right)} d x \\
&=\cot a\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}-\frac{1}{1+2 x \sin a+x^{2}}\right) d x \\
&=\cot a\left[\tan ^{-1} x-\frac{1}{\cos a} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x+\sin a}{\cos a}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty} \\
&=\cot a\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{\cos a}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-a\right)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Integrating $I’(a)$ back to $I(a)$, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
I\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)- \underbrace{I(0)}_{=\pi\ln 2}  &=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \cot a\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{\cos a}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-a\right)\right] d a \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} \underbrace{ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\left(\cot a-\frac{1}{\sin a}\right) d a}_{=\ln \left(\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)} + \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{a}{\sin a} d a}_{K}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
K &=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{a}{\sin a} d a=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} a\, d\left[\ln \left(\tan \frac{a}{2}\right)\right] \\
&=\left[a \ln \left(\tan \frac{a}{2}\right)\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \ln \left(\tan \frac{a}{2}\right) d a \\
&=\frac{\pi}{6} \ln \left(\tan \frac{\pi}{12}\right)-2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{12}} \ln (\tan a) d a \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{6} \ln (2+\sqrt{3})+\frac{4}{3} G,
\end{aligned}
$$

where $G$ is the Catalan’s constant and the last integral from [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/983551/732917).

Now we can conclude that
$$
\boxed{I=I\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3} \ln (2+\sqrt{3})+\frac{4}{3} G}
$$